# How do you pay Yugoloths?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

Yes, I'm back with another Yugoloth question.

So Yugoloths are known as mercenaries, primarily for Devils in the Blood War but also for powerful mortals and other beings, if the price is right. My question is, what do you pay them with?

I've seen it suggested that they take souls. What would they do with them though, since they can't make any more Yugoloths? It says in the MM that they need souls to power a ritual to bring one of them back if they were killed on Gehenna, but I don't know if this occurs often enough to be worth it to them. Furthermore, how do non-Devils acquire souls for trade besides their own?

The other option is gold and other kinds of material wealth. What the hell would Yugoloths do with those? I could see them hoarding gold and material wealth purely out of their cosmic Neutral Evil nature, but it seems like a waste, and that they would be smart enough to put gold to some use. Buying powerful magic items or equipment seems redundant since they're already decently powerful fiends.

**TL;DR ⁠— What forms of payment do Yugoloths accept and how do they make use of them afterwards?**

Comment: What ... they don't take Averniun Express cards?

Answer (score 11):

## [Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus) and [Rise of Tiamat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/rise-of-tiamat#TheRiseofTiamat) suggests that they take gold as payment.

But in reality I would assume that they would accept any commodity valuable in Lower Planes or on Material Plane.

Will they take souls? Sure, even if souls are non needed for some kind of daemonic ritual (and soul-fueled rituals is a big trope in DND and fantasy in general), soul trade is a big thing in Nine Hells, and they can easily trade them for what they actually need.

Will they take gold? Sure, they can trade it in any Material Plane world, or they can take it to Mammon which deals in mundane treasures in addition to souls.

Will they take rare magical items? Sure, even if they won't use them (though for fiend there no such thing as enough power), they can give them to their agents or even trade to someone else.

Will they take promise of favor? Sure, price of a favor owned by a strong entity cannot be measured.

Will they take information? Sure, they will kill (often literally) to get information on Books of Keeping